# iwconfig results differ when used as root or us plain user

Tags: networking, encryption

If I call iwconfig as user or as root, I get nearly the same result.
However, as root I get one more line: "Encryption key:off".
My Router says: "Encryption type ￼ WPA2 / WPA3 (secure)"

So, why says iwconfig "Encryption key:off" when run as root and why "off" thougt my network is encrypted?

Confused,
ulrich

Answer (score 2):

iwconfig still has the remnants of methodologies long since deprecated. Encryption key is a great example.

Back in the earlier days of wireless networking in Linux, including Ubuntu, one could connect entirely from the command line by setting the wireless access point (SSID), WEP* encryption key and all relevant details using iwconfig. There is no way to set WPA2/WPA3 details with iwconfig, primarily because the much easier way is Network Manager.

iwconfig is, however, still very useful to display, but not manipulate, some wireless settings. You can still tell that you are or are not connected, the SSID, bit rate, channel, etc.

In your case, the readings with sudo are entirely correct. There is not any WEP encryption key currently set. As well, the exact encryption key, if any, should not be disclosed to non-privileged (sudo) users.

References: `man iwconfig` and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102519/how-to-connect-to-wifi-that-has-a-encryption-key-in-terminal

*WEP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy

> Wired Equivalent Privacy (WEP) was a severely flawed security
> algorithm for 802.11 wireless networks. Introduced as part of the
> original IEEE 802.11 standard ratified in 1997

Answer (score 0):

`root`, the system administrator, has access to more system information than `$USER` has.